# Can we override standard java apis in Android?

Tags: java, android

Is there any way, by which I can override standard JAVA APIs in Android?

I mean:-

When one of my class, calls a JAVA standard API such as "`FileOutputStream`, `FileInputStream` etc" as below, it should invoke my own method and my own method will invoke the standard APIs:-

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

InputStream out = new FileInputStream(file);
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(FilePath); //Here FilPath is of type string etc
```

My requirement is that before invoking actual java standard API, my class should call my own method with the same name of the API and this my own method will internally call actual Java standard API.

I hope, my question is clear enough. But, if there are any doubt/queries etc, please reply to me.

Regards,
Adarsh

Comment: if class is not final, then you can override it

Comment: You can try to extend it and override the methods. But not all class/methods can be extended/overrided as Autocrab mentioned.